# Trying to access google spreadsheet python, can't get credentials

Tags: python, google-sheets, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to send data to google spreadsheet by python. Many tutorials later, I got stuck with the following error.

When I run this Python code:

```
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.tools import run_flow
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser

CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxgleusercontent.com'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxx'


flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
client_id = CLIENT_ID,
client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET,
scope = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://docs.google.com/feeds',
          redirect_uri = 'http://example.com/auth_return'
)

flags = argparser.parse_args(args=[])
storage = Storage('creds.data')
credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
print "access_token: %s" % credentials.access_token
```

I get this (which is fine)

http://static.indjango.com/python-gspread/screen-8.png   (not allowed to post pics yet)

Problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/gs/gs.py", line 43, in <module>
    credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 135, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/tools.py", line 235, in run_flow
    credential = flow.step2_exchange(code, http=http)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 135, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 2102, in step2_exchange
    headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1609, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1351, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1272, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1059, in connect
    raise SSLHandshakeError(e)
SSLHandshakeError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)
```

What can I do to fix this?

[This](http://www.indjango.com/access-google-sheets-in-python-using-gspread/) particular tutorial.

Comment: So this traceback occurs when you click 'accept' or when?
You should probably change the redirect url to `http://localhost:8080/`.